# How to Attach a database file with application so that it can work on a client pc in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Can anyone tell me which database type should use in C# programming to store some data locally? I have used SQL Server database file and built a simple application but when I put this to another PC, it says

> Could not connect to SQL Server Client
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: you have to install sql server in the other computer too

Comment: You also have to set up a connection string for that installation.

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server database you should install SQL Server in other pc , or you can use another dbs like Access

Comment: please tell me which database is better , which can attach only one or two DB Files with installation Media to Work on another PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a JSON file or sqlite, both of them do not requiere any installation on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install SQL Server in the other PC to run it local.
Another option is use some portable database, like sqllite, or access.

Or, try to use database server and access your database remotly.